# "empty field" when updating, if no image is selected don't update the database?

Tags: php, pdo

I have here the code for the updating the image, the updating is working fine when I select an image.  But when I try to do some updating without changing the image it is successfully updated.  When I look at my database the field is empty.  Whenever I try to update it and just leave the image as is it just saves an empty field.  When I try to to update and select an image to change the current image in the database it's working fine. I don't know what's wrong with it, there's no error.  Can somebody please help me with this?

**user.class.php**

```
public function upload($id,$FILE_NAME,$FILE_SIZE,$FILE_TYPE)
{
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE tish_images SET  FILE_NAME=:FILE_NAME,FILE_SIZE=:FILE_SIZE,FILE_TYPE=:FILE_TYPE WHERE id=:id");

$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $error )
{
    if ($error != UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
    {
        $errors[] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key] . ' was not uploaded.';
        return FALSE;
    }
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp  = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
    if($file_size > 2097152)
    {
        $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
        return FALSE;
    }
    try
    {
        $stmt->bindParam( ":id", $id);
        $stmt->bindParam( ":FILE_NAME", $file_name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam( ":FILE_SIZE", $file_size, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam( ":FILE_TYPE", $file_type, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->execute();

        $desired_dir="image_uploads";

        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false)
        {
            mkdir($desired_dir, 0700);
        }
        if(is_file($desired_dir.'/'.$file_name)==false)
        {
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$desired_dir.'/'.$file_name);
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $new_file=$desired_dir.'/'.$file_name.time();
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$new_file);  
            return TRUE;             
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      echo $e->getMessage();
      return FALSE;
    }   
}
}
```

**update.php**

```
<?php

include_once 'DB.php';

$FILE_NAME = isset($_GET['FILE_NAME']) ? $_GET['FILE_NAME'] : '';
$FILE_SIZE = isset($_GET['FILE_SIZE']) ? $_GET['FILE_SIZE'] : '';
$FILE_TYPE = isset($_GET['FILE_TYPE']) ? $_GET['FILE_TYPE'] : '';

if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
$id = $_GET['id'];

  if($crud->upload($id,$FILE_NAME,$FILE_SIZE,$FILE_TYPE))
  {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully Updated!'); </script>";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Updating Failed!');</script>";
  }
}

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p><strong>Survey Update</strong></p>
    <br />

  <div id="Survey-Update">
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
      <table class='table table-bordered'>

         <?php echo $FILE_NAME; ?>
         <input type="file" name="files[]"  value="" multiple/>
         <br />
         <br />
         <input type="submit"/>

</table>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are all fields empty? If not, which one is empty? You basically "pseudo-coded" your own answer in your question - if image isn't selected, then do X. If a new image is selected, then do Y. Test for that condition.

Comment: yes..all fields are empty

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you our

> if(!empty($_FILES['fieldname']['name'])){ // upload} else {// dont upload }